# role of ISP in defeating Dos DDoS

Tags: denial-of-service, isp

What is the role or responsibility of my ISP to protect my network that is connected through their network to the Internet  against DDoS / DoS  ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your contact with the ISP. Most ISPs just connect you to the internet and deliver any traffic addressed to you, including DoS/DDoS traffic. There are multiple ways to protect yourself against attacks, and some ISPs provide some features for you (like black holing some traffic) so you can protect yourself.

Additional DDoS protection services usually have to be bought and implemented separately, from your ISP or from a specialised DDoS protection service.

Comment: It's worth noting that your ISP's security department will certainly be interested in cases where a DDoS attack is occurring, especially if it is being perpetrated by another customer.

Comment: If you can prove somebody is "attacking" you to to cause you grief, then that could be treated as criminal activity. But it would most likely start with opening a case with the police any way. Depending on which country you are in - some places have better cyber security deparments

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @SanderSteffan on the point that it depends on your contract with your ISP.
However, (except if your ISP has some shady business on the side - maybe allowing its infrastructure to be another link to a DDoS execution chain) any legit ISP will be really concerned about a DDoS attack through their network, as it

1. adversely affects their reputation
2. negatively impacts their internet service and infrastructure performance
3. can possibly earn them a blacklisting of their IPs with the IANA (or whichever authority they fall under), which will in turn affect their customers
4. can get them legally implicated (sued).

Most ISPs, due to these (and other) reasons, will always implement some sort of mitigation against DDoS or any similar attack coming through their gateways. It's bad for business.